# How can I add a comment form?

Tags: views, nodes, forms, comments, 9

I'm using views to display the fields of nodes. I prefer to use fields because it allows me to use relationships (bring in author profile picture etc.). Adding the *Content: Comments* field shows the list of comments as well as the comment form for each node. However, when hiding and rewriting the result and/or using the replacement pattern for *Content: Comments*, the comment form disappears.

What methods can I use to display the comment form for each node?

Comment: well for starters whay not make a custom block and attach it to you view as a footer ... 
then look at the way core comments form works and build the form into that block ?

Comment: If I place a custom block into the view's footer, it will only show one block per view. I'm trying to place the comment form as a field per node. There was a module called Views PHP for Drupal 7, which allowed inserting PHP into the rows, however this was considered bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, when hiding and rewriting the result/and or using the
> replacement pattern for Content: Comments, the comment form disappears
> and only the comment list remains.

It's due to a Views UI bug as I was able to replicate the issue on a fresh install.

A workaround you can do is to do the re-writing via template file rather than via UI.

In your theme's /templates folder add:

views-view-fields--**view-name**--[**machine-name**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg).html.twig

and print the view fields there

```
{{ fields.title.content }} {# title field #}

{{ fields.comment.content }} {# comment field #}

{{ fields.field_name.content }} {# some other field #}
```

Flush all caches so template gets pickedup.